# libgdx : Scene to scene transition taking time in ios

Tags: ios, libgdx, scene

in libgdx IOS game [built using robovm backend] while moving from one scene to another scene, it takes almost 3-4 seconds. It works fine on desktop and android devices(takes 1-2 seconds). 
No new assets are loaded while new scene loading. So I am not sure why its taking time.

and its running quickly on IOS emulators but slow in actual device(i ran it on IPAD MINI).

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `changeScreen(screen)` method in the `ApplicationListener` interface?

Comment: is changeScreen(screen) a method from ApplicationListener interface ?

Comment: No. But you can also be extending `Game` which implements `ApplicationListener` himself. That provides you access to all the ApplicationListener + some screen support options. Sorry for the misunderstanding.